# Backpropagation of softmax function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, calculus

I'm trying to find out how the backpropagation of the tf.nn.softmax() function in tensorflow works in order to use it in my project. So for that I implement the following simple network to verify the derivatives of the softmax layer from tensorflow network similar to the mathematically derived derivatives.

```
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[5])
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[5])

w=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5]))

logits = tf.multiply(x,w)

y = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

loss = tf.pow(y - y_true,2)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

train_x = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
train_y = [3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0]

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# Following function is to print essential layer values required.
def get_val():
    print('LOSS  : ', sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x:train_x,y_true:train_y}))
    print('COST  : ', sess.run(cost,feed_dict={x:train_x,y_true:train_y}))
    print('Y     : ', sess.run(y,feed_dict={x:train_x,y_true:train_y}))
    print('LOGITS: ', sess.run(logits,feed_dict={x:train_x,y_true:train_y}))
    print('W     : ', sess.run(w,feed_dict={x:train_x,y_true:train_y}))

# before training
get_val()

# normal gradient decent optimizer used to calculate weight values
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1).minimize(cost)

# train only for one time
sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={x:train_x,y_true:train_y})

#after training
get_val()
```

Here you can see the values I got using **get_val()** function.

```
**Before Training**
LOSS  :  [ 7.8399997, 14.44,      23.04,      33.640003,  46.24     ]
COST  :  25.040003
Y     :  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
LOGITS:  [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
W     :  [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

**After Training**
LOSS  :  [ 8.916067, 15.904554, 24.835724, 35.293324, 37.2296  ]
COST  :  24.435854
Y     :  [0.01402173, 0.01194853, 0.01645466, 0.0591815,  0.8983936 ]
LOGITS:  [-0.16000001, -0.32000008  0.,          1.2800003,   3.9999998 ]
W     :  [-0.16000001, -0.16000004,  0.,         0.32000008,  0.79999995]
```

[image: Here you can see the function for weight derivatives that needs to be verified...!!!]

```
y_true = train_y
m = 5
alpha = 1 # learning rate
x = train_x
```

Using this function, I'm going to calculate the weights after the first training.

These are the weight values I got using this function.
**[-0.1792, -0.4864, -0.9216, -1.4848, -2.176 ]**

But it is not similar to the weight values I got after training the tensorflow network.
These are the weight values after the training.
**[-0.16000001, -0.16000004,  0., 0.32000008, 0.79999995]**

Can anyone explain me why the my function did not give the weight values as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Above equation is the derived equation for the weight derivatives. And weight update can be done accordingly with the help of gradient descent optimizer.